# Comma placed just before name of author in citation, with the Journal of Fluid Mechanics .bst style file

Tags: punctuation

**Edited.**

Technical context:
I use a Mac. I use TeXShop. I use BibTex, and BibDesk. I have all jfm (journal of fluid mechanics) necessary files in the folder the of the tex file.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{jfm}
\usepackage{natbib,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsrefs}
\bibliographystyle{jfm}
\title{X}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

some text\citep[Einstein 1905]{einstein}

\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

where my bibliography file sample is

```
@article{einstein,
    author = {Einstein},
    year = {1905}}
```

but this code gives:

[image: pictured problem]

And I want to remove the comma before Einstein...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `jfm` document class and the `jfm` bibliography style do not be part of the TeXlive distribution. Are the corresponding files available online somewhere?

Comment: Does JFM refer to the Journal of Fluid Mechanics? LaTeX templates are here: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/information/author-instructions/preparing-your-materials

Comment: I've edited the post. I have jfm.cls and probably jfm bib style but still. What are the names of jfm bibliography style files please? I had the jfm package before my question in the folder of the tex file.

Comment: @someone - The filename extension of all bibliography style files is `.bst`.

Comment: @Mico, I have the jfm.bst file.

Comment: @Werner, yes, it refers to Journal of Fluid Mechanics. I have the templates. But still the error.

Comment: why can't we have some examples of journal.tex and journal.bib files on journals sites seriously? I am wondering sometimes...

Comment: Using an up to date MacTeX distribution and the template files from the site to which @Werner provided a link, I am unable to replicate the spurious-comma issue. Specifically, `\citep{einstein}` generates "(Einstein 1905)".

Comment: I have TexShop 5.22. Damn. Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: Maybe I have "troubles" in my tex files in hardware...

Comment: The optional argument in `\citep` is for a page number, don't add the author name there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use quotation marks in my bib file instead of { } (maybe because I use BibDesk) around references, care for spaces between word and "=" symbols, not use quotation marks for the date, and remove the amsrefs package. But I succeeded.

This works:
@article{einstein,
author = "Einstein, Albert",
year = 1905}

with just \citep{einstein}